# SBI buddy integration in ios app

Tags: swift, xcode, wallet

I want to integrate SBI buddy wallet into my iOS app, but I am unable to find any reference.
Can anyone provide the reference for integrating SBI buddy wallet into iOS app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't integrate it because in order to communicate with this app you will need their public `API`. And I don't think this it is available publicly.

Comment: Yeah seems like that. Need to do some more RnD. Thanks for your reply